# How to render a static file in Grails?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-controller

I am pretty new to Grails and trying out stuff.

I have created a controller `HelloController` and placed it in the grails-app/controllers directory

here is the code in the HelloController class

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.*;
import grails.transaction.Transactional;

public class HelloController {              

    def index() {           


        render("hello world") 
    }
}
```

This works fine when i do `grails run-app` and then open the page http://localhost:8080/AppName/hello

As a next step I want to move the hello world to a .gsp file and then render the contents of the file

so i have created the folder  `grails-app/views/hello` and created an index.gsp file in the folder with the content

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

What should be my next step to make sure that content from this file is rendered ?

Tried to read on the `respond` method but that does not seem to help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have any data to send from the controller so return nothing:

```
def index() {           
}
```

Grails will display your `index.gsp` file correctly, simply because the file name and the action name match.

Doc on controllers: http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#controllers

Comment: Grails *is* awesome. Next step: send data from your controller to your .gsp :)

Comment: and  the next step, read docs before proceeding further, so you know how to do basic things